# Java ArrayList Help

Tags: java, arraylist

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class WTFAMIDOINGWRONG 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ArrayList<Integer> intsAR = new ArrayList<Integer>(5);
        intsAR.add(3, 1);

    }
}
```

So, I've been fooling around with this for about an hour and I haven't the slightest Idea what I could be doing wrong. No matter what I do, it's convinced the arraylist has no size and everything is therefore out of bounds. If anyone could tell me what I'm doing wrong I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: Why don't you simply use `instAR.add(1);`? It will not require any index.

Comment: Ok, the issue here is that I'm trying to satisfy a requirement for a programming course I'm taking. It says I must add a new item to the middle and end of the list. So I can't simply use intsAR.add(1);.

Comment: Then use array, `int[]`, instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An `ArrayList` is backed by an `array`, so when you specify the initial capacity, you are specifying how large of an array to allocate. This is important because it specifies how much memory the `ArrayList` will occupy sequentially.

However, the `size` of the `ArrayList` specifies how many items are actually in the list. Once the list reaches a certain size (relative to the capacity of the backing array), the backing array will be reallocated to take up additional space.

If you wanted to create an `ArrayList` of 10 items, all with 0, you would do:

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for ( int i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) {
   list.add(0);
}
```

Now you could insert an item at position 3 (or somewhere in the middle) if you wanted to.

Comment: I can't get it to work. I tried i < list.size() earlier, but that just brings me back to why it's not working in the first place,ha.

Comment: Sure. You might also want to look at the source code for ArrayList to get a better understanding of how it works.

Comment: A shorter way to write this: 
`List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(Collections.nCopies(10, 0));` or `List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(); list.addAll(Collections.nCopies(10, 0));`.

Answer (score 0):

Because the `size` of your `list` is ZERO. Yes, you are actually constructing it by specifying the `initialCapacity`, but that doesn't mean `size`. Are you getting my point? You can say that taht will just reserve the space for future.

BTW, `size()` documentation clearly states that, it is the number of elements in the list. Now, I hope you know what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot insert into an empty list in position 3 - what would be the first 2 elements then? With empty list only `intsAR.add(0, 1);` will work

Comment: is it possible then, to just set a default value for every item in the list? I tried using a loop to add a value to everything and I just received the same out of bounds error.